# dojox.gfx.Moveable convert screen coordinates to world coordinates for dragging

Tags: svg, matrix, draggable, coordinate-transformation, dojox.gfx

**tl; dr**
How would I use the CTM returned by:

```
var ctm = canvas.rawNode.getScreenCTM();
```

to modify a `dx, dy` vector in screen coordinates, such that it is in world coordinates?  i.e. `{ dx: 1, dy: 0}` should become `{ dx: 3.6, dy: 0}` given the above example of an SVG with viewBox `0 0 1800 1800` in a window 500px wide.

I thought the following would work:

```
  var ctm = canvas.rawNode.getScreenCTM();
  // Turn this into a dojox/gfx/matrix Matrix2D
  var ctmm = new matrix.Matrix2D({xx: ctm.a, xy: ctm.b, dx: ctm.c,
                                  yx: ctm.d, yy: ctm.e, dy: ctm.f});
  // Invert this
  var itm = matrix.invert(ctmm);
  // Multiply screen coords by transform matrix
  var worldshift = matrix.multiplyPoint(itm, shift.dx, shift.dy);
  console.log('ctm ', ctm, ', shift ', shift, ' became worldshift ', worldshift);
  shift.dx = worldshift.x;
  shift.dy = worldshift.y;
```

But `itm` comes out full of NaN and Infinity.

**long version of question follows with CodePen samples**

I know the basic maths behind this but found myself stumped trying to do it with matrix transformations.  The documentation seems to avoid this subject.  The situation is:

- SVG node has viewBox definiting world coordinates, say 0,0 to
  1800,1800
- SVG node is in a document that scales its to the window
  size, about 500px wide So world coords in the SVG (1800 x 1800 units)
  do not map 1:1 to screen coords.. each pixel across is 1800/500 = 3.6
  world units
- dojox/gfx/Moveable uses dojox/gfx/Mover whose
  `onMouseMove` function passes the amount it moved by in screen
  coordinates:

  this.host.onMove(this, {dx: x - this.lastX, dy: y - this.lastY});

That last argument is passed into `dojox/gfx/Moveable.onMoving` as the `shift` argument and might be e.g. { dx: 1, dy: 0 } if the mouse moved right by a pixel.

If we dumbly allow the framework to apply this to the translation transform of the shape being dragged, its position does not exactly match the mouse coordinates: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/RxpoMq (this works fine in the dojox demos because their SVG coordinate system matches the screen coordinate system 1:1).

I found some inspiration at http://grokbase.com/t/dojo/dojo-interest/08anymq4t9/gfx-constrainedmoveable where Eugene says "override onMoving on your object and modify the "shift" object so it never moves a shape outside of a specified boundaries.", this seems a good point to modify the `shift` object, so my next attempts declare a new type of `dojox/gfx/Moveable` and override `onMoving`.

I have tried using matrix transformations to get the Screen CTM of the SVG (which comes in an object of `{ a, b, c, d, e, f }`) and use it as a `dojox/gfx` `Matrix2D` (`{ xx, xy, dx, yx, yy, dy }`) using straight matrix operations.  The aim is to modify the `shift` object to convert screen units to world units before it is used on the shape's transformation matrix, but found myself very confused.  For a start the CTM seems to have a large dy of about 50 which immediately makes the shape shoot off the bottom of the screen.  Here's my latest very messy and broken attempt: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/EoWNOb

I can manually take the CTM's x and y scale values and apply them to the shift object: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/KZWapa

How would one use matrix operations such as `Matrix2D.invert()` and  `Matrix2D.multiplyPoint()` to take the coordinate system of the SVG, product a transformation matrix to convert from screen coordinates to world coordinates, and apply that to the dx,dy that the mouse moved by?

Answer (score 0):

I got a working example, by taking only `a` and `d` from the `DOMMatrix` populating only the `xx` and `yy` elements of the `Matrix2D`: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/mpWgrO

```
 var MyMoveable = declare(Moveable, {
    onMoving: function(/* dojox/gfx/Mover */ mover, /* Object */ shift){
      // console.log('mover ', mover, ' shift ', shift);
      // shift comes in screen coordinates
      // Get the Screen Coordinate Transform Matrix
      var ctm = canvas.rawNode.getScreenCTM();
      // Turn this into a dojox/gfx/matrix Matrix2D
      var ctmm = new matrix.Matrix2D({xx: ctm.a, yy: ctm.d});
      // Invert this
      var itm = matrix.invert(ctmm);
      // Multiply screen coords by transform matrix
      var worldshift = matrix.multiplyPoint(itm, shift.dx, shift.dy);
      console.log('ctm ', ctm, ', shift ', shift, ' became worldshift ', worldshift);
      // Replace the shift dx,dy vector with the transformed coordinates
      shift.dx = worldshift.x;
      shift.dy = worldshift.y;
    }
  });
```

With this, the red circle moves in sync with the mouse cursor.

Looks like I was overzealous in using the `DOMMatrix` attributes, trying to use all elements to fill out the `xy`, `yx` etc elements of my `Matrix2D` to use as the basis of the transformation matrix to use on the mouse movement vector.  I've found the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix rather difficult to follow, because it doesn't lay out the matrix elements in a grid so I thought a, b, c, d, e, f were simply laid out in a 3x3 grid:

```
{ a, b, c,
  d, e, f,
  0, 0, 1 }
```

However the '3D Equivalent' part of the docs indicate it's actually some kind of 4x4 matrix (here I use ? for an unspecified element, I'm not sure what the defaults would be):

```
{ a, b, ?, ?,
  c, d, ?, ?,
  ?, ?, ?, ?,
  e, f, ?, ? }
```

So I'm still rather confused, but do at least have a solution using `Matrix2D` operations.

I also tried briefly to use pure SVG operations to create a SVGPoint and transform it using DOMMatrix operations, but the transformation matrix comes out with offsets of 100 or 200 and I've given up on it: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/BJWEZw